# How to redirect to a page after wp_signon with elemntor form?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have an elementor form which is a kind of registration. I create a new user, and make login. All work fine, after submit he create a user and make a login but the redirect is not working.
The submit form show a loading icon. but when i look at the network tab in chrome inspect item I saw the page that redirected.
Hope this is understandable.

here is my code:

```
$credentials = [
     'user_login' => MY_USERNAME,
     'user_password' => MY_PASSWORD,
     'remember' => 1
];
   
user_login($credentials );
wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ."/dashboard");
exit;

.
.
.
function user_login($credentials){
   if(is_array($credentials )){
    wp_signon( $credentials); 
  }
}
```